# Checking Status of Admin and Super Admin while logging in

Tags: php

Working on a Project which have several admins and one super admin..
I have created a common table for admin's. Tables have fields username,password,location and status.

I have created a single login page. For admin I need username and location in session.But for super admin I need only username in session. The php code is as shown below:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
 session_start();
$Username=$_POST["t1"];
$Password=$_POST["t2"];
$Status=$_POST["t3"];
$location=$_POST["l1"];
$q=mysql_query("select * from admin_login where username='$Username'");
$rs=mysql_fetch_row($q);

  if(($rs[0]==$Username)&&($rs[1]==$Password)&&($rs[4]==$location)&&($rs[3]==$Status))
{   
 if($_SESSION["status"]=admin)
     {
         $_SESSION["user"]=$Username;
         $_SESSION["location"]=$location;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    alert('Admin logged in successfully');
    </script>"; 
    header("Refresh:0;http://localhost/e_classified/admin/a_activity.php");
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    alert('Incorrect details, Enter correct details');
    </script>";
    header("Refresh:0;http://localhost/e_classified/super admin/login.html");
}
}
 if(($rs[0]==$Username)&&($rs[1]==$Password)&&($rs[3]==$Status))
{
if($_SESSION["status"]==sadmin)
     {
         $_SESSION["user"]=$Username;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    alert('Super Admin logged in successfully');
    </script>"; 
    header("Refresh:0;http://localhost/e_classified/super%20admin/s_activity.php");
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    alert('Incorrect details, Enter correct details');
    </script>";
    header("Refresh:0;http://localhost/e_classified/super admin/login.html");

}

}

?>
```

The problem is that while logging in for any admin/superadmin it opens in a same page..i.e s_activity.php

Comment: Sure you do.... Recheck your `$q` variable

Comment: $q is working fine.. if i use only one if condition for admin alone i.e by deleting if condition for super admin..then it is working fine..

Comment: Its working fine untill it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your IF statement. You're not creating a logical evaluation. You need to use the correct operator and I think you ment to evaluate it to a specific string, "admin". Try this:

```
if($_SESSION["status"] == "admin") {
    $_SESSION["user"] = $Username;
    $_SESSION["location"] = $location;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>\r\n";
    echo "alert('Admin logged in successfully');\r\n";
    echo "</script>\r\n"; 
    header("Refresh:0;http://localhost/e_classified/admin/a_activity.php");
}
```